# Checking an editText that is on the Shared prefs settings screen

Tags: android, regex, sharedpreferences

I want to know if there is a way to check what someone is entering on the shared prefs/settings screen for validation. The user touches the Ip enter options, an edittext dialog pops up and I am trying to restrict what they can enter to something like a standard IP address(ie.   0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255)  I have looked in numerous online forums and saw examples of different things with REGEX and patterns and this is what I have so far, but absolutely nothing is happening....Can anyone help me out? I would greatly appreciate it!

```
    public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    private EditTextPreference ipTextBox;
    private String whatWasTyped;
    private String previousText = "";
    private Editor myEditor;

    final Pattern IP_ADDRESS = Pattern
            .compile("^((1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]|\\d?\\d)\\.){3}(?:1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]|\\d?\\d)$");
    private String IP_FROM_PREFS = "ipAddressPref";
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    /**
     * The onCreate method handles thing when starting this activity, 
     * mainly display the activity_settings.xml.
     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // pattern for IP address validation
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.activity_settings);

        // prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // Get a reference to the preferences
        ipTextBox = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
                IP_FROM_PREFS);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key)
    {
        // check prefs value for IP.

        if (key.equals(IP_FROM_PREFS))
        {

            whatWasTyped = prefs.getString(IP_FROM_PREFS, "");
            CharSequence s = whatWasTyped;
            if (IP_ADDRESS.matcher(s).matches())
            {
                previousText = s.toString();
                            myEditor = prefs.edit();
                            myEditor.putString(IP_FROM_PREFS, previousText);
                myEditor.commit();

            } else
            {
                //if the format does not match, put up an error message
                            // or something.

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // Setup the initial values
        // mCheckBoxPreference.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,
        // false) ? "Disable this setting" : "Enable this setting");
        // mListPreference.setSummary("Current value is " +
        // sharedPreferences.getValue(key, ""));

        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        previousText = prefs.getString(IP_FROM_PREFS, "");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

}
```

Since this is something created on the shared prefs screen, there are no button id, etc...

Comment: in this line: addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.activity_settings); you should be putting the activity_settings.xml in XML folder not the layout folder

Comment: sorry, I correct my pattern: \b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d?\d)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d?\d)\b

Answer (score 0):

Just writing

```
 whatWasTyped.replace(s, previousText);
```

will not assign the the previousText to the SharedPreference you need to assign it back to the shared preference and commit.

Comment: Yes, I just thought of this. Careless me! I will make those adjustments and respond back.

Comment: So I edited the file a little, shortening the pattern and commit the change if what the person entered was in a good format. I did this through myEditor.